# OpportunityLineItem shows UnitPrice with 3 places after decimal

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, pricebookentry

I have an opportunity that has 3 products and each product has a list price of $600 and sales price (UnitPrice) of $400.  The amount field on the opportunity is showing $1,199.99 instead of $1200 as we'd like.

I ran a query in the developer console against the OpportunityLineItem table for this opportunity record and the UnitPrice is showing $399.996 for each line item.

How can this be and why is it not showing $400.  I did some googling and saw there is some feature about "More decimals on price", but this doesn't seem to be relevant here.

We are using a single currency in our salesforce org and "UnitPrice" is a standard salesforce field. Looking at it, it shows (16,2) for the scale/precision

How can I fix this issue so our UnitPrice for each product shows $400 instead of $399.996?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating the `UnitPrice` field to explicitly set it to `400`?

Comment: It is already showing $400.00 when I go edit the Opportunity Product record @AdrianLarson

Comment: Updating it to set 400 as the value might still help. Maybe toggle it to 401 and then back to 400.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and the record modified stamp did update, but the query results still show $399.996 as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: In developer console I was able to edit the line items unitprice value to 400, but not from within the salesforce UI.  This fixed the issue with this one record, but does not explain why the values were this way in the first place.

Comment: Seems like a floating point error somewhere. You were using standard UI?

Comment: Yes, standard UI... I was able to edit it manually in developer console and fix this issue, at this point I can't reproduce it.